# Is it possible to only expose the typeclass interface of a return value?

Tags: haskell, existential-type

In the following code all that I ever do with the return value of `foo` is use its `Show` interface

```
foo :: String
foo = "asdf"

main = do
    print foo
```

Is there a way to modify the type signature of`foo` to enforce this, forbidding people from treating the string as a list of characters and only letting them access it though the abstract type class interface? I think it might be possible with existential types but I have no idea how.

---

The reason I want to do this is because in the HDBC database library all the functionality is available as methods of a [`IConnection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/latest/doc/html/Database-HDBC.html#t%3aIConnection) type class. I am writing the function that creates the database connection and I want to know if its possible to have its return type reflect the abstract interface instead of returning a concrete Sqlite3 [`Connection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC-sqlite3/latest/doc/html/Database-HDBC-Sqlite3.html#t%3aConnection).

Now that I searched a bit I see that there is a [ConnWrapper](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/latest/doc/html/Database-HDBC.html#t%3aConnWrapper) datatype available but I still can't understand how this all fits together. Is returning a ConnWrapper the only way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's indeed possible with existential types, but it's quite possibly a [bad idea](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

The way you would do it with an existential type is `ConnWrapper`, like you said:

```
data ConnWrapper = forall conn. IConnection conn => ConnWrapper conn
```

That type is relatively straightforward: It's an `IConnection` dictionary together with a value of a type compatible with it. If `x :: conn`, and `conn` is an instance of `IConnection`, then `ConnWrapper x :: ConnWrapper`. Given `y :: ConnWrapper`, you know nothing about its value's type other than that it's an instance of `IConnection`. So you can say `case y of ConnWrapper z -> disconnect z`, but you can't say `case y of ConnWrapper z -> z` -- there's no Haskell type you can give to that.

(`ConnWrapper` is also an instance of `IConnection` directly, and since the class is pretty simple, that means you pretty much never need to pattern-match on `ConnWrapper` directly. You can just use `disconnect y` and so on.)

If you were making the API, I'd strongly suggest reconsidering along the lines of the post I linked above, or at least understanding that approach. Many uses of ExistentialTypes in Haskell are actually more complicated than a non-existential approach. For example, you should see why `data Foo = forall a. Show a => Foo a` is (almost) equivalent to `String`. It looks like the HDBC may be intended to be used this way, though...

Comment: Some followup questions: 1) is it possible to define the IConection instance without needing to write down every single method [like they did here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/latest/doc/html/src/Database-HDBC-Types.html#ConnWrapper)? (I'm guessing you can't use newtypes because of having to store the method dict...) 2) Assuming we had the power to rewrite their interface how would we go about getting rid of that type class? Using a record of functions? I'm wondering if there is a problem with the fields being publicaly "modifiable" like that.

Comment: 1) Not really. 2) A record of values (some of which are functions) would be one reasonable thing to do. Nothing is modifiable in Haskell. :-) You can make a new record, of course, but you can always make a new type too.